# Argument '[controllerName]' is not aNaNunction, got undefined, when converting to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Getting started with TypeScript. I have this working without TypeScript, but in converting am getting an error.

I have the following controller:

```
"use strict"
module app.blogApp {
    class BaHomeController {
        entries: any[];

        static $inject = ["$http"];

        constructor(
            private $http
        ) {
            this.loadEntries();
        }

        private loadEntries() {
            this.$http.get("api/blogEntries").then(function(response) {
                this.entries = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Which is transpiled to:

```
"use strict";
var app;
(function (app) {
    var blogApp;
    (function (blogApp) {
        var BaHomeController = (function () {
            function BaHomeController($http) {
                this.$http = $http;
                this.loadEntries();
            }
            BaHomeController.prototype.loadEntries = function () {
                this.$http.get("api/blogEntries").then(function (response) {
                    this.entries = response.data;
                });
            };
            BaHomeController.$inject = ["$http"];
            return BaHomeController;
        })();
    })(blogApp = app.blogApp || (app.blogApp = {}));
})(app || (app = {}));
```

Which is loaded via HTML:

```
<section data-ng-controller="BaHomeController as vm"></section>
```

Why does this generate the Angular error:

> Error: ng:areq
>   Bad Argument
>   Argument 'BaHomeController' is not aNaNunction, got undefined

I read that this means Angular might not be able to find the controller. With this new syntax, how can I verify that the controller name is correct?

PS What's a aNaNunction?

Comment: You need to post the typescript

Comment: Where do you actually register the controller?

Comment: Oops. Added it @CHBuckingham

Comment: Can you clarify @RyanCavanaugh? I am using the controller as syntax, so the route defines the template. The template specifies which controller to use, and the controller definition above should define the controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a line like this somewhere (assuming you have not registered the module already):

```
angular.module('blogApp', []).controller('BaHomeController', app.blogApp.BaHomeController);
```

Comment: Hmm I'll have to figure out how to do this in TypeScript

Comment: Well if you have angular.d.ts (DefinitelyTyped for angular) installed, then the code above is exactly how you do it in TypeScript.  Just do it in a TypeScript module outside of any of your controllers.